# Difference between homogeneity and stationarity?

Tags: time-series, heteroscedasticity, stationarity

I had to do recently a literature overview on homogeneity tests (e.g., Pettitt test, standard normal homogeneity test, etc.) for hydrological time series data and I got a little bit confused. 
Doesn’t homogeneity sound a lot like stationarity? Are they different in meaning?

Comment: This might be useful:
http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1672/what-is-the-difference-between-a-homogeneous-stochastic-process-and-a-stationary